# Tensor Flow - using saved model won't return correct results

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

My specs:
Windows 10 64,
Python 3.6,
Tensorflow 1.0.1.

I've been trying to train and use neural network agains MNIST dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data", one_hot=True)

tf.reset_default_graph()

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500
n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

current_epoch = tf.Variable(1)

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))
                      }
    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1,n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))
                      }

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2,n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))
                      }

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3,n_classes])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
                      }

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output

saver = tf.train.Saver()

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0

            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x,epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x:epoch_x, y:epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

        correct = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(prediction,1), tf.arg_max(y,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
        saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")

train_neural_network(x)
```

After that I passed one of MNIST images through trained model:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
mn = cv2.imread('352.png')
mn = cv2.cvtColor(mn,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mn2 = np.array(list(mn.flatten()))

x = tf.placeholder('float')
y = tf.placeholder('float')

with tf.Session() as sess:

    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.restore(sess,"/tmp/model.ckpt")

    result = (sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[ mn2 ]}),1)))
    print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x:[mn2]}))
    print(result)
```

Unfortunately, with a model accuracy of ca. 95% I keep getting wrong results - not only they are wrong but also not consistent among different runs

Let's say I pass image of number 8, and I get 9, 4, 3...

The model file model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 saved to hard drive is about 10 megabytes. When I try to restore model while doing the training for every loop (as suggested on pythonprogramming.net course) model seems not to update, because files are only 1KB.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One thing you need to do is to name the TensorFlow graph variables of the model. The python variable names such as `x` and `y` are not stored to the file. So you need to name the variables in the TensorFlow graph, and then reference the graph variables in the restored model.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, but simply naming the variables didn't help. I managed to solve this by altering the code a little:

First I define variables within training function and add `with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

def train_neural_network(x):
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')`
(....)
then initializa Saver objest just before saving:
            
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")

I do similar thing in

Comment: when loading a model.
Full description here:
[https://kevincodeidea.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/tensorflow-save-and-load-a-model-in-a-serious-way-from-different-files/]